# How do I create a snap for my Java 21 app?

Tags: ubuntu, snapcraft

I cannot follow the [official guide](https://snapcraft.io/docs/java-applications) because it has not been updated.

I have an executable JAR file and source code available to all.

How do get my app on the snap store without lengthy trial and error?

Here is my repo: https://github.com/pacman-admin/pacmancode

I tried the example on the official guide but it was very broken.

JReleaser is also broken.

I have a JDK (openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16 LTS) installed.

I was expecting the example to work but it just complained about my snapcraft version being too recent.

```
'core18' is not supported on this version of Snapcraft.                        
Recommended resolution: Install from or refresh to the '7.x' channel.          
For more information, check out: https://snapcraft.io/docs/base-snaps
```